Possible bug in DefaultAzureCredential, in the ManagedIdentity approach
I'm working with an Azure Storage Account, via Azure.Storage.Blobs, and using DefaultAzureCredential as my credentials. The program is crashing out when trying the ManagedIdentityCredential alternative, and if I set the ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true option, then the code works properly.
My understanding of DefaultAzureCredential is that it would try all of the alternative approaches, until they have all failed, and only then explain why each approach failed (because if any of them worked, then the failures don't matter)... so I think this might be a bug (if so, let me know where to report it, because I can't work out which repo owns it).
I have an MCVE which repeats the problem for me, although it may be a problem for others to repeat, because I suspect the reason that the Managed Identity approach is failing, is because it's being blocked by my employer's web gateway blocking the URL that it's trying to contact (the exception is at the end of this question).
Project File
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Storage.Blobs" Version="12.20.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Program.cs
namespace ManagedIdentityCredentialProblem;

using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs;
using Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models;

internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var storageAccountName = "youraccountnamegoeshere";
        var serviceUri = new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net");
        var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(
            new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
////                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
            }
            );
        var blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(serviceUri, credential);

        string containerName = "managedidentitycredentialproblem";
        var blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

        var cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
        await blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType.None, null, cancellationToken)
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

If I run that code as shown (either debugging from Visual Studio, or by running the EXE; but both are on my machine, which is a physical computer rather than something in the cloud), it fails with the exception below, on the final line of the program. However, if I uncomment the commented line, the code succeeds, which implies that one of the other credentials used by DefaultAzureCredential worked - so I don't think it should be complaining when the ManagedIdentity approach fails.
Exception
Unhandled exception. Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication failed: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (GlobalBlock)

Content:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
          <script src="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/javascript/sw.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <title>Blocked Request: http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&amp;resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F</title>
        <style type="text/css">
                body { padding: 5px }
                p { margin: 1em 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 12px; color: #333 }
                li { margin: 1em 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 12px; color: #333 }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 style="margin: 0 0 45px 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #6569FE;">Redacted Security</h1>
<!--Contents-->
        <p>The Web request to http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&amp;resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F has been blocked.
        <p><b>Reason: Category (Global Blocklist)</b></p>
        <p>If you feel that the Web site you requested has been blocked inappropriately, please contact your system administrator.</p>

<!--/Contents-->
</body>
</html>


Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: REDACTED
Proxy-Connection: REDACTED
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1192

See the troubleshooting guide for more information. https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/identity/managedidentitycredential/troubleshoot
 ---> Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 403 (GlobalBlock)

Content:
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
          <script src="/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/files/javascript/sw.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <title>Blocked Request: http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&amp;resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F</title>
        <style type="text/css">
                body { padding: 5px }
                p { margin: 1em 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 12px; color: #333 }
                li { margin: 1em 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 12px; color: #333 }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <h1 style="margin: 0 0 45px 0; font-family: Tahoma,Sans; font-size: 24px; font-weight: bold; color: #6569FE;">Skyhigh Security</h1>
<!--Contents-->
        <p>The Web request to http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&amp;resource=https%3A%2F%2Fstorage.azure.com%2F has been blocked.
        <p><b>Reason: Category (Global Blocklist)</b></p>
        <p>If you feel that the Web site you requested has been blocked inappropriately, please contact your system administrator.</p>

<!--/Contents-->
</body>
</html>


Headers:
Cache-Control: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: REDACTED
Proxy-Connection: REDACTED
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 1192

   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, HttpMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.HandleResponseAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, HttpMessage message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ImdsManagedIdentitySource.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateCoreAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AppTokenProviderImpl(AppTokenProviderParameters parameters)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.SendTokenRequestToAppTokenProviderAsync(ILoggerAdapter logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.GetAccessTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, ILoggerAdapter logger)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.ClientCredentialRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<<RunAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Utils.StopwatchService.MeasureCodeBlockAsync(Func`1 codeBlock)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.ApiConfig.Executors.ConfidentialClientExecutor.ExecuteAsync(AcquireTokenCommonParameters commonParameters, AcquireTokenForClientParameters clientParameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilderExtensions.ExecuteAsync[T](AbstractAcquireTokenParameterBuilder`1 builder, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientCoreAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, String claims, Boolean enableCae, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.MsalConfidentialClient.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(String[] scopes, String tenantId, String claims, Boolean enableCae, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityClient.AuthenticateAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenFromSourcesAsync(TokenCredential[] sources, TokenRequestContext requestContext, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.CredentialDiagnosticScope.FailWrapAndThrow(Exception ex, String additionalMessage, Boolean isCredentialUnavailable)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenImplAsync(Boolean async, TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential.GetTokenAsync(TokenRequestContext requestContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.SetResultOnTcsFromCredentialAsync(TokenRequestContext context, TaskCompletionSource`1 targetTcs, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetAuthHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.TokenRequestState.GetCurrentHeaderValue(Boolean async, Boolean checkForCompletion, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AccessTokenCache.GetAuthHeaderValueAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.AuthenticateAndAuthorizeRequestAsync(HttpMessage message, TokenRequestContext context)
   at Azure.Storage.StorageBearerTokenChallengeAuthorizationPolicy.AuthorizeRequestInternal(HttpMessage message, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.BearerTokenAuthenticationPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.InnerProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RedirectPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.RetryPolicy.ProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline, Boolean async)
   at Azure.Core.Pipeline.HttpPipelineSynchronousPolicy.InnerProcessAsync(HttpMessage message, ReadOnlyMemory`1 pipeline)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.ContainerRestClient.CreateAsync(Nullable`1 timeout, IDictionary`2 metadata, Nullable`1 access, String defaultEncryptionScope, Nullable`1 preventEncryptionScopeOverride, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient.CreateInternal(PublicAccessType publicAccessType, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobContainerEncryptionScopeOptions encryptionScopeOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, String operationName)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsInternal(PublicAccessType publicAccessType, IDictionary`2 metadata, BlobContainerEncryptionScopeOptions encryptionScopeOptions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync(PublicAccessType publicAccessType, IDictionary`2 metadata, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at ManagedIdentityCredentialProblem.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\ManagedIdentityCredentialProblem\Program.cs:line 25
   at ManagedIdentityCredentialProblem.Program.<Main>(String[] args)


Can you explain bit clearer? because DefaultAzureCredential will work such methods it will first check the (Environment, Workload identity, Managed identity, Azure CLI, Azure PowerShell, Azure Developer CLI, Interactive) if all approach failed you will get an error. Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/authentication-overview#sequence-of-authentication-methods-when-you-use-defaultazurecredential

Certainly. The exception shown above is coming from the ManagedIdentity option, which will not work because I'm on-premise, so I am expecting that approach to fail. However, one of the other approaches will work (as proven if I uncomment the commented line). My expectation is that the failure of that approach should not be allowed to crash the application, because one of the other approaches works. I cannot put the ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true code in the real code, because  once deployed, that will be running in Azure as a managed identity, so will actually require that approach.

You can raise new issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues

Thanks https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/44999
